# Run a Recycle-Proof Task every 'x' minutes when an ASP.Net website starts up in ASP.Net 4.0

Tags: asp.net, scheduled-tasks

I would like to fire a method 'ProcessBatch () ' to run every 'x' minutes when an ASP.Net app starts up.

I think I will have to add code for this to Application_Start event.

**What is the best way of doing this, so that when the website has its app pool recycled then the scheduled task that is running is treated as a web  request and allowed to complete?**

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a scheduled task that runs "every x minutes" on a web server.

Some people write services that run on a client computer which pings the site every now and then. But for that you need that client to be up-and-running.

One workaround is, like you say, the Application_Start event, but your application may run longer than just a few minutes. We do not actually know when that is.

You could run your task someplace else, like the Session_Start event (whenever a new user opens one of your pages), or even the BeginRequest event if you write your own HttpModule.

In those events, you could remember the time the task was run for the last time (like a static, or in the ApplicationState maybe) to keep it from running hundreds of times per minute once your site has a huge load of users.

Hope this helps?

Answer (score 0):

Also, depending on where your site is hosted, you may be able to use that provider's scheduled-task system. [Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/schedule-backend-tasks/) has one, RackspaceCloud and [DiscountASP.NET](https://demo.discountasp.net/scheduled-task.aspx) as well.